# JSON and MySQL UPDATE query

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm trying to get info from a JSON msg out of ZeroMQ into MySQL by Python. This is the piece of code I'm attempting to run:

```
for i in json_msg["PropertyInfoMsg"]:
    db2 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", db="db")
    cursor2 = db2.cursor()
    sql = """UPDATE settings SET value=%s WHERE name=%s""" % (i["PropertyType"].lower(), i["PropertyValue"].lower())
    cursor2.execute(sql)
    db2.commit()
    cursor2.close()
```

But it's comming back as:

> 1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax

I could really use a second pair of eyes at this at this point in time, I feel like I'm completely missing it.

Priting out the sql variable returns:

```
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
UPDATE settings SET value=i["PropertyType"].lower() WHERE name=i["PropertyValue"].lower()
```

Comment: What does `sql` print out to when you add in the 2 string values?

Comment: Updated the original post to include your awnser's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your parameters with single quote:

```
sql = """UPDATE settings SET value='%s' WHERE name='%s'""" % (i["PropertyType"].lower(), i["PropertyValue"].lower())
```

Also you must confirm your json data is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the query this way :

```
cursor2.execute("UPDATE settings SET value = %s WHERE name = %s",(i["PropertyType"].lower(), i["PropertyValue"].lower()))
```